# Android Code Error causing Application stops unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Following is the code, I modified from an open source, and below is the logcat showing error I checked the code so many times but dont know what is the problem. please help in regard.

```
/**
 * MainActivity
 */
public class MainActivity extends AbstractMainActivity implements
        Memory.OnMemoryListener {

    private static final int[] tiles_fruits = { R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2,
            R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.a4, R.drawable.a5, R.drawable.a6,
            R.drawable.a7, R.drawable.a8, R.drawable.a9, R.drawable.a10,
            R.drawable.a11, R.drawable.a12, R.drawable.a13, R.drawable.a14,
            R.drawable.a15, R.drawable.a16, R.drawable.a17, R.drawable.a18,
            R.drawable.a19, R.drawable.a20, R.drawable.a21, R.drawable.a22 };

    private static final int[] tiles_foods = { R.drawable.d1, R.drawable.d2,
            R.drawable.d3, R.drawable.d4, R.drawable.d5, R.drawable.d6,
            R.drawable.d7, R.drawable.d8, R.drawable.d9, R.drawable.d10,
            R.drawable.d11, R.drawable.d12 };

    private static final int[][] icons_set = { tiles_fruits, tiles_foods };

    private static final int[] sounds = { R.raw.gupp, R.raw.winch,
            R.raw.chtoing, R.raw.kito, R.raw.kato, R.raw.ding, R.raw.ding2,
            R.raw.ding3, R.raw.ding4, R.raw.ding5, R.raw.ding6, R.raw.dong,
            R.raw.swirlup, R.raw.swipp };

    private static final int[] not_found_tile_set = { R.drawable.not_found_fruits, R.drawable.not_found_foods };
    private Memory mMemory;
    // private int mNotFoundResId;
    private MemoryGridView mGridView;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        PreferencesService.init(this);
        newGame();
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    protected View getGameView() {
        return mGridView;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    protected void newGame() {
         int set = PreferencesService.instance().getIconsSet(); 
            mMemory = new Memory( icons_set[ set ], sounds , not_found_tile_set[ set ], this);
            mMemory.reset();
            mGridView = (MemoryGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            mGridView.setMemory(mMemory);
            drawGrid();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    protected void preferences() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mMemory.onResume(PreferencesService.instance().getPrefs());

        drawGrid();

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mMemory.onPause(PreferencesService.instance().getPrefs(), mQuit);

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    public void onComplete(int countMove) {
        int nHighScore = PreferencesService.instance().getHiScore();
        String title = getString(R.string.success_title);
        Object[] args = { countMove, nHighScore };
        String message = MessageFormat
                .format(getString(R.string.success), args);
        int icon = R.drawable.win;
        if (countMove < nHighScore) {
            title = getString(R.string.hiscore_title);
            message = MessageFormat.format(getString(R.string.hiscore), args);
            icon = R.drawable.hiscore;

            PreferencesService.instance().saveHiScore(countMove);
        }
        this.showEndDialog(title, message, icon);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    public void onUpdateView() {
        drawGrid();
    }

    /**
     * Draw or redraw the grid
     */
    private void drawGrid() {
        mGridView.update();
    }

}
```

Below is the Logcat showing error.

```
06-03 14:54:17.095: E/Trace(19172): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nyt.game.play.fun/com.nyt.game.play.fun.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):   at com.nyt.game.play.fun.ui.MainActivity.newGame(MainActivity.java:72) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):     at com.nyt.game.play.fun.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150) 06-03 14:54:17.392: E/AndroidRuntime(19172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
```

below is icons_set

```
private static final int[][] icons_set = { tiles_fruits, tiles_foods };
```

and here is the getIconsSet method

```
public int getIconsSet() {
        return getPrefs().getInt(PREF_ICONS_SET, ICONS_SET_FRUITS);

    }
```

Complete Code is here

[Code is here](http://tareenweb.net/dummy/PlayNLearn.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3`

because `int set = PreferencesService.instance().getIconsSet();` returns 3 an your array `icons_set` has only two arguments.

You make sure that the array has enough elements.

Comment: What should `getPrefs().getInt(PREF_ICONS_SET, ICONS_SET_FRUITS);` do?

Comment: Dont know how to explain, but PREF_ICONS_SET needs to set the Icons_Set, and ICONS_SET_FRUITS, is the selected ICONS set index number.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem solved by adding another Icons_set. bcoz there were 2 indexed 0 and 1, and that was causing problem in other methods.